# Creating strong password bug

Tags: javascript

I was doing this [problem on hacker earth](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/strong-password/problem), (can ignore the question)

Basically in the below code snippet

```js
function minimumNumber(n, password) {
   const mapStrength = {
       numberProp: false,
       lowerCase: false, 
       upperCase: false,
       specialChar: false
   }
// Number of characters less than 6, add those many characters to reach 6 -> The buffer characters
    let charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong = 0
    let bufferLength = (6-n) > 0 ? 6-n : 0 
    
    console.log(`This is buffer:`,  bufferLength)
    // Split password and itt
    password.split('').forEach(character => {
        // Checking if character is number
        if (Number.isInteger(character) && !mapStrength.numberProp) mapStrength.numberProp = true
        // Checking if character is
    
        if (character.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/) && (character === character.toLowerCase()) && !mapStrength.lowerCase) mapStrength.lowerCase = true
        if (character.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/) && (character === character.toUpperCase()) && !mapStrength.upperCase) mapStrength.upperCase = true
        if (character.toLowerCase() === character.toUpperCase()) mapStrength.specialChar = true 

    })
    console.log(mapStrength)

        // Calculating Number of false
    Object.values(mapStrength).forEach(charge => {
        if (!charge) charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong += 1
    })

         console.log(charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong, bufferLength)
      if (bufferLength > charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong) return bufferLength
      if (charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong > bufferLength) return charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong
      return bufferLength

}

minimumNumber(3, 'zss');
```

why is my mapStrength.lowerCase coming out to be false? In this line I though I am setting to true?

```
 if (character.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/) && (character === character.toLowerCase()) && !mapStrength.lowerCase) mapStrength.lowerCase = true
```

Comment: You forbid characters, and you want in a same time have a lowercase characters.

Comment: If you're using regular expressions, there's no need to iterate the string:  regexes are perfectly capable to do that on their own. Just do `if (/[a-z]/.test(passwd)) -> password has a lower letter` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your test:

```
if (character.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/) && (character === character.toLowerCase()) && !mapStrength.lowerCase) {
  mapStrength.lowerCase = true
}
```

The first condition only applies if `character.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/)` - in other words, if `character` is *not* alphabetical. The `[^` matches any character that is *not* one of the following characters in the character set. Use `/[a-z]/i` instead (which is the same as `[a-zA-Z]`, only less repetitive):

```js
function minimumNumber(n, password) {
   const mapStrength = {
       numberProp: false,
       lowerCase: false, 
       upperCase: false,
       specialChar: false
   }
// Number of characters less than 6, add those many characters to reach 6 -> The buffer characters
    let charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong = 0
    let bufferLength = (6-n) > 0 ? 6-n : 0 
    
    console.log(`This is buffer:`,  bufferLength)
    // Split password and itt
    password.split('').forEach(character => {
        // Checking if character is number
        if (Number.isInteger(character) && !mapStrength.numberProp) mapStrength.numberProp = true
        // Checking if character is
    
        if (character.match(/[a-z]/i) && (character === character.toLowerCase()) && !mapStrength.lowerCase) mapStrength.lowerCase = true
        if (character.match(/[a-z]/i) && (character === character.toUpperCase()) && !mapStrength.upperCase) mapStrength.upperCase = true
        if (character.toLowerCase() === character.toUpperCase()) mapStrength.specialChar = true 

    })
    console.log(mapStrength)

        // Calculating Number of false
    Object.values(mapStrength).forEach(charge => {
        if (!charge) charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong += 1
    })

         console.log(charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong, bufferLength)
      if (bufferLength > charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong) return bufferLength
      if (charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong > bufferLength) return charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong
      return bufferLength

}

minimumNumber(3, 'zss');
minimumNumber(3, 'zsS');
```

You could make the code more readable by just using a single condition that assigns to `mapStrength.lowerCase` regardless:

```
if (character.match(/[a-z]/)) {
  mapStrength.lowerCase = true;
}
if (character.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
  mapStrength.upperCase = true;
}
```

```js
function minimumNumber(n, password) {
   const mapStrength = {
       numberProp: false,
       lowerCase: false, 
       upperCase: false,
       specialChar: false
   }
// Number of characters less than 6, add those many characters to reach 6 -> The buffer characters
    let charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong = 0
    let bufferLength = (6-n) > 0 ? 6-n : 0 
    
    console.log(`This is buffer:`,  bufferLength)
    // Split password and itt
    password.split('').forEach(character => {
        // Checking if character is number
        if (Number.isInteger(character) && !mapStrength.numberProp) mapStrength.numberProp = true
        // Checking if character is
        if (character.match(/[a-z]/)) {
          mapStrength.lowerCase = true;
        }
        if (character.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
          mapStrength.upperCase = true;
        }
        if (character.toLowerCase() === character.toUpperCase()) mapStrength.specialChar = true 

    })
    console.log(mapStrength)

        // Calculating Number of false
    Object.values(mapStrength).forEach(charge => {
        if (!charge) charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong += 1
    })

         console.log(charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong, bufferLength)
      if (bufferLength > charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong) return bufferLength
      if (charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong > bufferLength) return charRequeiredToMakePasswordStrong
      return bufferLength

}

minimumNumber(3, 'zss');
minimumNumber(3, 'zsS');
```